# create alert in grafana based on number fields having value below threshold

Tags: grafana, graphite, grafana-templating, grafana-alerts, graphite-carbon

We have grafana dashboard which has x axis has time and y axis with free memory in the server(in gb). Dashboard has fields for 100+ servers in a particular datacenter. Threshold for free memory is below 12gb. If a server has memory below 12gb it’s critical. We want to create alert on data center level. Example if 75 servers has free memory below 12gb it should trigger an alert. Is that possible to handle this condition in grafana query functions ?  Source for this grafana dashboard is from graphite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to implement this with removeAbove and removeBelow functions.